# I’m trying to push to master after I run a github action

Tags: github, github-actions

When I run my action I have a program that changes a file and I want to have it automatically push to the github after it runs. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Github Actions Runner have git pre-installed. You can simply execute all standard Git console commands directly. Of course, you still have to make sure to configure the name and e-mail that should be displayed for the commits. It's a good idea to just use the Github Actions bot for this. So you can simply add a step to your workflow that looks something like this:

```
      - name: Push
        run: |
          git config --global user.name github-actions
          git config --global user.email 41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com
          git add .
          git commit -m '[Automated action] Build'
          git push
```